# Image processing pipeline for segmenting cell nuclei

Tags: python, computer-vision, image-segmentation, morphological-operations

I'm seeking a better image processing pipeline to essentially segment cell nuclei in fluorescence images. So far, I've tried a bunch of morphological operations, e.g. modifying this [scikit-image pipeline](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_fluorescence_nuclear_envelope.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-fluorescence-nuclear-envelope-py). My implementation

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io, morphology, filters, color


# Ground truth mask
mask = io.imread('/path/to/mask.png')
mask_rgba = colorize(mask, T_GREEN)

# a) Raw
image_FM = io.imread('/path/to/image_FM.png')

# b) Blur
smooth = filters.gaussian(image_FM, sigma=3)

# c) Opening
structure = morphology.disk(radius=10)
opened = morphology.opening(smooth, selem=structure)

# d) Closing
closed = morphology.closing(opened, selem=structure)

# e) Threshold
otsu = filters.threshold_otsu(closed)
thresh = closed > otsu

# f) Fill in
structure = morphology.disk(radius=20)
filled = morphology.closing(thresh, selem=structure)

# Calculate Intersection over Union
IoU = calc_IoU(filled, mask)
out = f"IoU = {IoU:.1%}"
print(out, '\n' + '-'*len(out))

# Create figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=2, figsize=(15, 10))
axes[0, 0].imshow(image_FM, cmap='Greys_r')
axes[0, 1].imshow(smooth, cmap='Greys_r')
axes[0, 2].imshow(opened, cmap='Greys_r')
axes[1, 0].imshow(closed, cmap='Greys_r')
axes[1, 1].imshow(thresh, cmap='Greys_r')
axes[1, 2].imshow(filled, cmap='Greys_r')
axes[1, 2].imshow(mask_rgba, alpha=0.5)
# Aesthetics
titles = ['a) Raw', 'b) Blur', 'c) Opening',
          'd) Closing', 'e) Threshold', 'f) Filled in']
[ax.set_title(title) for title, ax in zip(titles, axes.flat)]
axes[0, 0].set_title('a) Raw')
axes[0, 1].set_title('b) Blur')
[ax.axis('off') for ax in axes.flat];
```

which results in an intersection-over-union (IoU) score of only 67%, which I think could definitely be improved upon.

[image: Sample 1]

Would be happy to hear any ideas/suggestions the community might have.

---

For full reproducibility, the code for the `colorize` and `calc_IoU` functions are

```
def colorize(image, T):
    # Convert to rgba
    rgba = color.gray2rgba(image, alpha=True)
    # Apply transform
    transformed = np.dot(rgba, T)
    rescaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(transformed)
    return rescaled

def calc_IoU(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = y_true > 0.5
    y_pred = y_pred > 0.5
    overlap = ((y_true == 1) & (y_pred == 1)).sum()
    union = ((y_true == 1) | (y_pred == 1)).sum()
    IoU = overlap / union
    return IoU
```

and the images:

##### Raw

[image: Raw image]

##### Mask

[image: Mask image]

---

#### Additional images

Additional sample images are available below.
https://surfdrive.surf.nl/files/index.php/s/GhZB2GkBLQX7aBM

Note that some nuclei may be missed in the mask.

Comment: How was the mast determined? Manually? if so, can you try to automate your manual process?

Comment: The mask was done manually, yes and automating it is the point of the script @PeterK. ;) but I'd like for the script to yield a better result. Many of the nuclei in the final segmentation are clearly poorly segmented.

Comment: @lanery, Do you have more examples for images?

Comment: @Royi Yes, added a few more, thanks.

Comment: Could you add a pair of images and masks?

Comment: @Royi Sure! It was getting cluttered so uploaded them to a zip folder that is divided into "fluorescence" and "mask" images (pairs have the same file names).